# How to change Div Class In Master page from Child page

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

I want to change div style (display) in master page **from my child page**.

I use :

```
    protected void ShowMsgText(int MsgID)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl MsgInner;
        MsgInner =((HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("MsgInner"));
        MsgInner.Attributes["class"] = "MsgInnerShow";
    }
```

MsgInner is my div id, But any change after run this !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have investigated the problem. I believe you have update panel in child page (aspx) and message div in master page. Update panel can update the controls which lie under it but it could not update control those are out side update panel. So you need to put update panel in master page.

**In Master Page**

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="ScriptManager1" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>              
                <div><strong>Demo for master page updation</strong></div>
                <div  id="divMaster" runat="server">
                    I am div in master page, going to change with ajax call
                </div>            

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**In content page (.aspx)**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

**In content page code behind (.aspx.cs)**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); //To check the effect of ajax call, must be removed
      HtmlGenericControl divMaster = (HtmlGenericControl) this.Master.FindControl("divMaster");
      divMaster.InnerHtml = "hello I am being change from child page";
}
```

Comment: MsgInner Tag is Server-Side, But where i whould be use :
MsgInner.Attributes["class"] = "MsgInnerShow";        in the master-page code-behind ?

Comment: IMO the the execution of child page finishes before the parent page control is rendered. Could you tell me exact scenario when you want to change the css

Comment: Ok, i have a message box in child page, i create a div base panel in my master page (in default is display:none), when the user click on "Show Message" in child page, this div panel go (display:inline) and then i want set data of Message to the div panel elements (ex: labels, buttons ,...) and this is dynamic message show !

Comment: Oh, i forget this, my Child Page Use a Update Panel

Comment: Yes, I test this without Updatepanel and it work. but my button is in updatepanel. any idea ?

Comment: @Armin Khodaei, I have updated my answer. I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Define a public property on your master page

MyMasterPage.Master.cs

```
private string _divClass = "DefaultClass";
public string DivClass
{
    get
    {
        return _divClass;
    }
    set
    {
        _divClass = value;
    }
}
```

Add this property to the HTML markup of the div on the Master page:

MyMasterPage.Master:

```
<div id="MyDiv" runat="server" class="<%=DivClass %>">
```

You can set this value the OnInit or OnLoad event of the child page.

ChildPage.aspx.cs

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        var master = Page.Master as MyMasterPage;
        if (master != null)
        {
            master.DivClass = "MyOtherClassName";
        }
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

Comment: I think The problem was around the Ajax updatePanel that is my Child page !

Comment: Yes, I test this without Updatepanel and it work. but my button is in updatepanel. any idea ?